# Date issue on dynamic generated fields magento2

Tags: magento2.2, dateformat

Invalid date issue on dynamic generated fields. Having multiple date filed in tier price. On deleting the rows from tier price , other rows from and to date value showing weird invalid date like "12/05/1905".

Using Magento2.2 Please check attached screenshot from more info.

```
class DateRangeTier implements ModifierInterface
{
    protected $arrayManager;

    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $tierPricePath = $this->arrayManager->findPath('tier_price', $meta, null, 'children');

        if ($tierPricePath) {
            $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                $tierPricePath,
                $meta,
                $this->getTierPriceStructure()
            );
        }

        //echo json_encode($meta);die;

        $meta['advanced_pricing_modal']['children']['advanced-pricing']['children']['tier_price']['arguments']['data']['config']['label'] = 'Manage Price Rules';

        $meta['advanced_pricing_modal']['children']['advanced-pricing']['children']['tier_price']['children']['record']['children']['website_id']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = false;


        $meta['advanced_pricing_modal']['children']['advanced-pricing']['children']['tier_price']['children']['record']['children']['cust_group']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = false;

        $meta['advanced_pricing_modal']['children']['advanced-pricing']['children']['tier_price']['children']['record']['children']['price_qty']['arguments']['data']['config']['value'] = 1;

        $meta['advanced_pricing_modal']['children']['advanced-pricing']['children']['tier_price']['children']['record']['children']['price_qty']['arguments']['data']['config']['disabled'] = true;

        /*echo "<pre>";
        echo json_encode($customPricing);
        echo "preee";die;*/


        return $meta;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data){
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
        return $data;
    }

    protected function getTierPriceStructure()
    {
        return [
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'children' => [
                        'from_date' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'dataType' => 'date',
                                        'formElement' => 'date',
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('From Date'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'from_date',
                                        'date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
                                        'sortOrder' => 5,
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'to_date' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'dataType' => 'date',
                                        'formElement' => 'date',
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('To Date'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'product',
                                        'date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
                                        'sortOrder' => 6,
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'reward_points' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('Reward Points'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'reward_points',
                                        'sortOrder' => 38,
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                            'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                            'validate-digits' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Added Custom columns to Tier Price. Using Magento2.2 .
From and to date is required field.
When i add more than one rows in tier price and selected different different date in all fields.
After that if i delete any row, all other rows date field values is changed.

Like if first row is having from date "05/16/2018" and to date "05/17/2018"

In 2nd row from date "05/18/2018" and to date "05/19/2018".
Now if i delete the 2nd row, the from and to date field value in first row   is showing as from date "01/20/1905" to date "05/20/2018".

Field added using adminhtml `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="neoCustomAdvancePricing" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Neo\Marketplace\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DateRangeTier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">95</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

[image: Multiple date field in tier price]

[image: Multiple rows with tier price]

[image: On deleting any row, from and to date in all other will be changed to past year like "12/02/1905"]